# SimpleDateFormat.format returns date as String but the hours, minutes and seconds are returned as 00:00:00.000

Tags: java, oracle, simpledateformat

I am retrieving a date column from oracle DB and passing it as a string in a HTTP API call. Although the column value in DB is `26/08/2015 12:58:42`, when I try :-

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+03:00'");
    this.requestDate = sdfDate.format(requestDate);
```

I get the `String` value as `2015-08-26T00:00:00.000+03:00` in API call URL.
Why is this happening and how to get the original hour, minutes and seconds?

**EDIT**: *I was querying the date column by ResultSet.getDate("column_name"). Its resolved when I used ResultSet.getTimestamp("column_name")*

Comment: How do you get the date from the database?

Comment: Try after removing .SSS'+03:00 from your formatter

Comment: I can't remove that, that's my API's URL format and its required

Comment: I am querying a simple "select * from table_name" and storing the date field in a date variable in DTO and then passing it in the mentioned function as requestDate

Comment: Use an ISO parser which can handle timezone offsets, everything else is a pain. Try JodaTime.

Comment: Post the code. It matters.

Comment: You need to use `getTimestamp()` to properly retain the time part of the `date` column. `getDate()` will return a `java.sql.Date` where the time will be set to 00:00:00

Comment: I tried your code with passing new Date (). And it prints actual values. Above comments must solve your problem

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks very much, its working with your solution

Comment: If you found one of the answers useful, mark it as answer. No need to change question title, if you tick the useful answer, it will show up as solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, Exception {
        Connection con = ConnectionDefinition.getOracleConnection();
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+03:00'");
        ResultSet rs = con.prepareCall("select sysdate from dual").executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            System.err.println(sdfDate.format(rs.getTimestamp(1))); // try this
            System.err.println(sdfDate.format(rs.getDate(1)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I got it from a_horse_with_no_name's comment above. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

   getDate() method of ResultSet Interface Returns Date object which contains only date without time.

EX: 2015-08-26 (as per your input)

   getTimestamp() method of ResultSet Interface returns Timestamp object which contains date as well as Time in 24 hours format.

Ex: 2015-08-26 12:58:42

after getting the respective objects you can apply format() method of SimpleDateFormat class to format the date.